# Add slightly wrong answer so google searchers find answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, wrong-answers

My Google searching last night on a specific error message gave me one result: a Stack Overflow question ( and then a number of derivatives: *Wow!* A lot of sites copy the SO content.) (I'd add the search terms here, but I don't want to mess up the searches of others.)

The question was only answered by the OP, and no votes for the question or the answer. The question was about the exact error that I was seeing, and the name of the question contained the very unique error message. The OP was using a very different environment then I was. (I'm coding C# in Visual Studio, OP writing SQL in Report Designer.)

The OP's single answer, posted and accepted by OP, did not solve my problem, but I have no doubt that it solved the OP's. (He had erroneous data in a SQL data set; I had correct data, but an incorrect version of a dll.)

Should I post my answer to that question? Incorrect for the original question, but correct for me and possibly future users? The question is a couple months old, so I don't think I would be confusing the original user. It would have saved me a couple of frustrating hours...

Comment: Why the down votes? Should I not have asked? I'll delete if inappropriate...

Comment: down votes on meta mean "I disagree" not "I think you shouldn't have posted this"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the OP asked about a different environment, I'd guess that your answer would not be able to solve *his* problem. As such your answer would not belong to his question.

You *can* (and possibly should) post your problem as a separate question (with a similar title) and post your answer to that.

*At most* you could add a comment linking to your new question noting that it's about a different problem with the same error message.

Comment: You should link to the existing question emphasising the differences otherwise yours may well get closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Does your solution answer *exactly the same question*? Not just the title/error message? If it doesn't, and you feel it is worthwhile (not too localised), you should ask and answer your own question. Putting a knowingly wrong answer against a question with an accepted answer doesn't seem like a good idea.